# Show that $n=\gamma(n)$ if and only if $\mu^2(n)=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I show that $n=\gamma(n)$ if and only if $\mu^2(n)=1$ where $\gamma(n)=\prod_{p|n}$ and $\mu$ is möbius function ?

---

I know that $\gamma$ and $\mu$ are both multiplicative functions for more information refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#Multiplicative_functions

Comment: What is $\gamma(n)$?

Comment: The kernel of n.

Comment: $\gamma(n)=\prod_{p|n}p$

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you having trouble with this proof? (You've been a user for almost a year and a half - surely you know that questions that are bare problem statements aren't usually well-received...)

Comment: I know that product as the [radical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) of $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\mu^2(n)=1$ if and only if $n$ is *square-free*, that is, not divisible by any square greater than $1$. So if the prime power factorization of $n\gt 1$ is equal to $p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$, where the $p_i$ are distinct, then $\mu^2(n)=1$ if and only if all the $a_i$ are equal to $1$, that is, if and only if $n=p_1p_2\cdots p_k$.

Comment: But how does that imply that $n=\gamma$?

Comment: By kernel you presumably mean the product of the *distinct* primes that divide $n$. Since $\mu^2(n)=1$ iff $n=1$ or all the exponents of the primes is $1$, that means that for $n\gt 1$, we have $\mu^2(n)=1$ if and only if $n$ is the product of the distinct primes that divide $n$.